# Spring Data Hibernate Error: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am stuck with a classical problem for which none of the tons of solutions do work for.

The following `Foo` entity should have a simple association with the `User` table.

```kotlin
@Entity
class Foo(
) {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    val id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString()

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "editor_user")
    var editor: User? = null

}
```

Here is the `User` entity

```kotlin
@Entity
class User(
    @Id
    val id: String,
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    var email: String = "",
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    var password: String = "",
    @Column(name = "active_session", nullable = false)
    var activeSession: String = "",
    @Column(name = "is_admin", nullable = false)
    var isAdmin: Boolean = false

) {}
```

And here is my `application-local.yaml` with the relevant configuration:

```yaml
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://${SQL_CONNECTION:localhost}:3306/${SQL_DATABASE:test}?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
    username: ${SQL_USER:root}
    password: ${SQL_PASSWORD:root}
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 4
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    generate-ddl: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
```

When I run the application the following bootup exception is thrown:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table immobilie add constraint FKdjkmdiv4qobj6v6ciwbqc1w91 foreign key (editor_user) references user (id)" via JDBC Statement
[...]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot add foreign key constraint
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar:8.0.26]
```

I have a problem figuring out *why* the foreign key cannot be added. The error is not very verbose on that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, usually this fails because the constraint is not enforceable i.e. some data does not fit the constraint. Try executing the following query to find out what data this is and after fixing that, it should succeed:

```
select * from immobilie i 
where i.editor_user is not null 
and not exists (select 1 from user u where u.id = i.editor_user)
```